# How can I once run For Loop in void OnGUI?

Tags: c#, unity, gui

I want once run GUI on screen same Initialization a number.
I try say my think In easiest way then please payattention to this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class guimanager : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool Isdone;
     void OnGUI()
    {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j+=20) {
            if (Isdone == true) {
                break;
            }

            GUI.Box(new Rect(j, j, Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2), "This is a test");
                print (j);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want keep my GUI.Box When end loop,So I need a boolean that when finish stop loop.

my problem Is frequent loop:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,......
```

GUI.Box will Show

but When I want break my loop:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5
```

GUI.Box won't Show!!!!

Can I show my GUI.boxes In my loop when finished?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class guimanager : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool Isdone;
     void OnGUI()
    {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j+=20) {
            if (Isdone == true) {
                break;
            }

            GUI.Box(new Rect(j, j, Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2), "This is a test");
                print (j);
            }
Isdone = true;
        }
    }
```

Why when I stop loop GUI.Box won't show!!!

Comment: You need to follow the coding standards for C#, for things like variable names and indentation. Heck, at the very least, pick one and be consistent. (Note: I'm not entirely certain that Microsoft has official style standards, but I think they do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are showing `GUI.Box` in your for loop after `break`. That is preventing your `GUI.Box` to draw.

What you have to do is simply draw your `GUI.Box` outside the for-loop. You can do it in a little bit better way, like,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class guimanager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool _isDone = false;

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            GUI.Box (new Rect (j * 20, j, Screen.width, Screen.height), "This is a test");
            if (_isDone)
                continue;
            print (j);
        }
    _isDone = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I use arry GUIes?????GUI.Box (new Rect (j,j, Screen.width, Screen.height), "This is a test"); I want have loop GUI for example: if j ==5 > for loop > i have five GUI.Boxes [] [] [] [] [] []